# ffmpeg : LIVE HLS Playback getting delayed over time

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

We are converting UDP Input to Live HLS output and pushing the chunks to a webdav server. Initial playback works fine, But the playback was delayed by almost an hour, when we checked after 15 hours. Not sure this is caused due to network as we use internet to push the chunks. Below is the ffmpeg command used.

```
ffmpeg -i udp://230.1.1.15:10000?fifo_size=10000000&overrun_nonfatal=1 -filter_complex [i:0xd49]yadif,setdar=256/144[v0];[i:0xd49]yadif,setdar=512/288[v1];[i:0xd49]yadif,setdar=640/360[v2];[i:0xd49]yadif,setdar=1280/720[v3] -f hls -map i:0xd4a -af aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0 -c:a:0 libfdk_aac -b:a:0 48000 -ar:0 48000 -map [v0] -b:v:0 100000 -maxrate:v:0 100000 -minrate:v:0 100000 -bufsize:v:0 200000 -s:v:0 256x144 -r:0 25 -sc_threshold 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -flags +global_header+cgop -c:v:0 libx264 -profile:v:0 baseline -level:v:0 3.0 -preset:v:0 fast -nal-hrd cbr -g 50 -map i:0xd4a -af aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0 -c:a:1 libfdk_aac -b:a:1 48000 -ar:1 48000 -map [v1] -b:v:1 200000 -maxrate:v:1 200000 -minrate:v:1 200000 -bufsize:v:1 400000 -s:v:1 512x288 -r:1 25 -sc_threshold 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -flags +global_header+cgop -c:v:1 libx264 -profile:v:1 baseline -level:v:1 3.0 -preset:v:1 fast -nal-hrd cbr -g 50 -map i:0xd4a -af aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0 -c:a:2 libfdk_aac -b:a:2 64000 -ar:2 48000 -map [v2] -b:v:2 700000 -maxrate:v:2 700000 -minrate:v:2 700000 -bufsize:v:2 1400000 -s:v:2 640x360 -r:2 25 -sc_threshold 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -flags +global_header+cgop -c:v:2 libx264 -profile:v:2 baseline -level:v:2 3.0 -preset:v:2 fast -nal-hrd cbr -g 50 -map i:0xd4a -af aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0 -c:a:3 libfdk_aac -b:a:3 64000 -ar:3 48000 -map [v3] -b:v:3 1000000 -maxrate:v:3 1000000 -minrate:v:3 1000000 -bufsize:v:3 2000000 -s:v:3 1280x720 -r:3 25 -sc_threshold 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -flags +global_header+cgop -c:v:3 libx264 -profile:v:3 high -level:v:3 4.0 -preset:v:3 fast -nal-hrd cbr -g 50 -var_stream_map a:0,v:0,name:148k a:1,v:1,name:248k a:2,v:2,name:764k a:3,v:3,name:1064k -master_pl_name master.m3u8 -hls_list_size 3 -hls_time 6 -hls_segment_filename https://usr:pass@example.com:8043/httppush/media_%v_%03d.ts -hls_flags delete_segments+independent_segments+discont_start https://usr:pass@example.com:8043/httppush/playlist_%v.m3u8
```

FFMPEG V4.3

```
ffmpeg version 4.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --extra-libs=-lpthread --extra-libs=-lm --bindir=/root/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree --enable-openssl
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
```

**With Split Filter:**

```
ffmpeg -i "udp://230.1.1.15:10000?fifo_size=10000000&overrun_nonfatal=1" -filter_complex "[i:0xd49]yadif[v];[v]split=4[1out1][1out2][1out3][1out4];[1out1]setdar=256/144[v0];[1out2]setdar=512/288[v1];[1out3]setdar=640/360[v2];[1out4]setdar=1280/720[v3];[i:0xd4a]aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0[a];[a]asplit=4[a0][a1][a2][a3]" -f hls -map [a0] -c:a:0 libfdk_aac -b:a:0 48000 -ar:0 48000 -map [v0] -b:v:0 100000 -maxrate:v:0 100000 -minrate:v:0 100000 -bufsize:v:0 200000 -s:v:0 256x144 -r:0 25 -sc_threshold 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -flags +global_header+cgop -c:v:0 libx264 -profile:v:0 baseline -level:v:0 3.0 -preset:v:0 fast -nal-hrd cbr -g 50 -map [a1] -c:a:1 libfdk_aac -b:a:1 48000 -ar:1 48000 -map [v1] -b:v:1 200000 -maxrate:v:1 200000 -minrate:v:1 200000 -bufsize:v:1 400000 -s:v:1 512x288 -r:1 25 -sc_threshold 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -flags +global_header+cgop -c:v:1 libx264 -profile:v:1 baseline -level:v:1 3.0 -preset:v:1 fast -nal-hrd cbr -g 50 -map [a2] -c:a:2 libfdk_aac -b:a:2 64000 -ar:2 48000 -map [v2] -b:v:2 700000 -maxrate:v:2 700000 -minrate:v:2 700000 -bufsize:v:2 1400000 -s:v:2 640x360 -r:2 25 -sc_threshold 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -flags +global_header+cgop -c:v:2 libx264 -profile:v:2 baseline -level:v:2 3.0 -preset:v:2 fast -nal-hrd cbr -g 50 -map [a3] -c:a:3 libfdk_aac -b:a:3 64000 -ar:3 48000 -map [v3] -b:v:3 1000000 -maxrate:v:3 1000000 -minrate:v:3 1000000 -bufsize:v:3 2000000 -s:v:3 1280x720 -r:3 25 -sc_threshold 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -flags +global_header+cgop -c:v:3 libx264 -profile:v:3 high -level:v:3 4.0 -preset:v:3 fast -nal-hrd cbr -g 50 -var_stream_map "a:0,v:0,name:148k a:1,v:1,name:248k a:2,v:2,name:764k a:3,v:3,name:1064k" -master_pl_name master.m3u8 -hls_list_size 3 -hls_time 6 -hls_segment_filename https://usr:pass@example.com:8043/httppush/media_%v_%03d.ts -hls_flags delete_segments+independent_segments+discont_start https://usr:pass@example.com:8043/httppush/playlist_%v.m3u8
```

Comment: You're deinterlacing the video stream four times, and you're filtering the audio four times as well. Filter it once in filter_complex and then use split filter to generate required number of streams. Apply any distinct filters (like setdar and scale) and then map those. But ultimately your server may not have enough resources to maintain realtime speed.

Comment: @Gyan Thanks for your reply. I am a newbiee to ffmpeg, can you please give me more info on how the split filter works. If possible can you share the updated command.

Comment: @Gyan,  I somehow managed to get the command working with the split filter. I am still seeing the delay in the playback after an hours of stream.  I have updated my question with the ffmpeg command with split filter. Can you check the above ffmpeg command and suggest for any changes.

Comment: @Gyan, I could still see the issue, with your above recommendation, even with very less cpu utilization. Do you have any suggestions?